# Change homepage of Phabricator to a dashboard

Tags: phabricator

Maybe I am a moron, but I have a very simple question: How do I change the homepage of an Phabricator installation to a dashboard? I can make a dashboard in Phabricator.... but how can I ensure, that this dashboard will be shown when a user does access the base uri of the installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, you have to make your dashboard in the global menu items the first one before the built-in homepage. Even if you have deactivated this default menu item. That solves my problem.

Some images to visual guide:

1. Create the dashboard with Home Icon.

[image: Creating dashboard with Icon]

2. Set up the dashboard on menu items:

[image: Edit menu configuration]

Comment: Plus, to make it unnoticeable, you may also change the Icon on Dashboard > Select Dashboard > Edit > change Icon (change to house icon) then include it as topmost item on edit Menu with Home as it's name.